# C++11: Difference between v = { } and v { }

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to ask if there is any difference between following two statements:

```
// C++11
std::vector<int> d {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> d = {1, 2, 3};
```

In both cases the sequence constructor gets invoked:

```
class A {
public:
  int a;

  A() {
    cout << "default constructor" << endl;
  };

  A(const A& other) {
    cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
  };

  A& operator =(const A& other) {
    cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
  }

  A(std::initializer_list<int> e) {
    cout << "sequence constructor" << endl;
  };

  A& operator =(std::initializer_list<int> e) {
    cout << "initializer list assignment operator" << endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  A a {1, 2}; // sequence constructor
  A b = {1, 2}; // sequence constructor
  b = {1, 2}; // initializer list assignment operator
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Doing e.g.

```
A myA{...};
```

will always invoke the appropriate constructor.

But doing

```
A myA = ...;
```

will do different things depending on the expression on the right-hand side of the assignment, as it might invoke the copy-constructor instead. Or optimize it out with copy-elision.

Also, if you have an array you have to use the assignment syntax.

Comment: You don't need the "assignment" syntax for arrays, at least not in C++11. Anyway, the `=` variant requires an implicit conversion (see duplicate.)

Comment: The bottom line is that for all intents and purposes, pretty much every compiler is going to handle both of the OP's cases (i.e. initializer lists) the same unless `auto` is on the left hand side.

Comment: @TimSeguine The compiler still has to follow the rules of the language, and the rules are different for each case. In most cases, the end-effect is the same, but it is not up to a compiler to decide. And I have seen real code with `explicit` multi-parameter constructors...

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah, which is why it is good to know the actual rules. But lies that are "almost" always true are good to know.